# How to get Current Currency rate using java?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, java-8

Currency rate are varying. How we can get that varying currency rate through java code, Without an API.
Like we get current date and time.

I found getting currency rate through API.Is there java provide any Predefined functions.

Comment: You mean like USD vs. CAD? This is not natively supported by any language I'm aware of. You would _need_ to use an API of some form.

Comment: If you figure out how to compute the currency rate without looking it up in an external system, you will have solved almost the entire field of economics and would probably get a nobel prize or two for it.

Comment: @JoachimSauer especially considering that there isn’t a single exchange rate anyway, as different market places may trade a currency at different rates at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible.

Date and time behavior is fixed (if today is Sunday, tomorrow is Monday) and relays on the host.
Currency values can increase or decrease without any pattern, it is also dependents on outer parties (country, war, events) which are not knows to the host.

If you wish to create such a program, you will have to relay on an API which polls for the most recent currency values.